# Can I convert an unit16_t to an "uint12_t"?

Tags: c++, casting, integer, can-bus

I have the issue that I need to compress two uint16_t numbers into an 2byte space.
I know that I lose information but the numbers higher than 12bit are not relevant for me.
The first 12bit shall be the one number and the last 12bit shall be the secound.
The output is needed for an CAN Message.
Has anyone an idea on how to solve this problem in C++?

this was my first try but it resulted in two bytes sized numbers as expected.

```
  byte OUT[2];

  union OUT_byte {
    byte bufferOUT[2];
    uint16_t OUT_array_int;
  } OUTb;

  OUTb.OUT_array_int = (double)(round(INPUT)); // casting from an double originaly

  for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(OUTb.bufferOUT); i++) {
    OUT[i] = OUTb.bufferOUT[i];
  }
```

This gives me two bytes an an array with my information.
Now I need two numbers compressed to 12bit in 3bytes.

Comment: What compiler and hardware do you have that support 12-bit integers? I doubt you have that. Instead read the full 16 bits and use *masking* (bitwise and `&`) to extract the 12 bits you need.

Comment: On a second note, what is `(double)(round(INPUT))` supposed to do? The `std::round` function returns a `double` value, so there's no need to cast it to `double`. And without evidence to say otherwise, I doubt that `INPUT` is in a floating-point format, so rounding it as a floating point won't work that well. Also, in C++ you should consider any need to do a C-style cast (like you do there) as an indicator that you're probably doing something wrong.

Comment: On another note, type punning through unions like you do is Undefined Behaviour in C++. You can only access the union member that was last written to and no other.

Comment: Truncating your two 16 bit integers down to 12 bits each still leaves you with 24 bits of information to store. You want to store that in 2 bytes, which typically is only 16 bits of storage. Does your platform have bytes that are at least 12 bites wide?

Comment: If your platform provides `std::uint12_t`, then a plain `static_cast` should be fine.  But remember that all fixed-width types are optional, and I would be surprised if it has both `std::uint12_t` _and_ `std::uint16_t`.

Comment: @TobySpeight I think that it is impossible. `CHAR_BIT` has to be at least 8 bits, `sizeof` has to be an integer and `std::int_Nt` types are exact. The only way to have `std::uin12_t` is if `CHAR_BIT == 12` in which case there can't be a `std::uint16_t`.

Comment: CPUs usually support 8, 16, 32, and 64 bit numbers. Anything else is **your own** creation. You can use 3 separate bytes, and use bit-shifting operators to pack the 2 12-bit numbers into 3 separate bytes, for example.

Comment: Side note in C++ do not use `union` but use `std::variant_t`. When you start reading the C++ standard documentation you will find there is a lot that can go wrong with union (UB)

Comment: @François that's exactly why it would surprise me.

Comment: @PepijnKramer In the golden age of C, programmers learnt that `union` was good for one single purpose: type punning and using a region of memory for _related_ purposes, just accessing the data through different types. Then in the dark ages of Visual Basic, all programmers were tortured and soon learnt that using variants for any purpose was misguided and also a pretty strong sign of bad program design. Then in the golden age of C++, we learnt that type-generic template programming could be used instead. ->

Comment: And then in the dark ages of C++11 and beyond, everyone involved had managed to forget all about the dark age of Visual Basic and about proper OO design in general. Enter: `variant_t`.

Comment: @Lundin Yeah after working with "COM"'s variant it took me a long time to even dare too look at `std::variant` and it still isn't my tool of choice. I only used union long long time ago to safe some memory (never used it for type punning). So std::variant_t isn't the best thing in C++, but at least better behaved than union. To summarize I wasn't really promoting std::variant ;) (I like to fail hard and fast, which means compile time whenever I can)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude There is no hardware that supports the 12bit integer but the CAN Protocol I need to implement calls for two 12bit numbers and I can't change that.

Comment: @98coolmen Oh I'm sure there has been a system sometime in history that had a native 12-bit type, almost any other size have been used. :) But the problem is still solved by bit-masking.

Comment: @PepijnKramer Fair enough but the reason why union is misbehaving in C++ is because an active choice was made by PC programmers in the ISO WG to make it misbehave. It is well-defined in C. And since union type-punning is _very_ common in hardware related programming, C++ is no longer suitable for such. But then of course a language with thousands of forms of poorly-defined behavior is probably not suitable for _any_ professional setting...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is normally solved by using a large enough type by a multiple of 8 bits. So in your case you would use `uint16_t` and ignore the 4 top bits.

However, if you actually need a bit-field consisting of multiple 12 bit adjacent chunks, you'd use a `uint8_t` array instead. Example (assuming big endian):

```c
uint8_t can_data[8] =
{
    (data0 & 0xFF0) >> 4, 
    (data0 & 0x00F) << 4 | (data1 & 0xF00) >> 8, 
    (data1 & 0x0FF), 
    ...
};
```

That is:

- data0 bits 11-4 into 1st byte bit 7-0
- data0 bits 3-0 into 2nd byte bits 7-4
- data1 bits 11-8 into 2nd byte bits 3-0
- data 1 bits 7-0 into 3rd byte bits 7-0

... and so on. As you can tell, this is a very cumbersome format to work with. It is a space optimization which comes at the cost of readability and performance both. So we'd typically avoid this format unless as a last resort. I *have* actually used something very similar myself in the real world, when I designed a compact wireless protocol that contained multiple 12 bit analog values.

In the world of CAN, then notably CANopen decided to make all analog values 16 bit, even though not many devices actually use that high resolution. It saved them from a lot of fuss like the above bit packing exercise though, so it was probably the correct call for an industry standard.

Comment: This is a more in-depth answer than mine. Good answer.

Comment: Thank you. The CAN Message Layout I need to program sadly calls for the two 12bit integers so you helped me alot. But some questions remain it doesnt work 100% yet. Why is there a bitmask in the 3.line of your code? when moving the data 4 bits over discards the rest anyway and why is the bitmask longer than the uint16_t itself or do I miss something?

Comment: @Lundin also shouldnt the data0 in line 4 be moved by 12 bits to the left?

Comment: @98coolmen The bitmask is 12 bits out of 16, used to select the part of the 12 bits that the line is targeting. By using a 12 bit bitmask we get a little bit more self-documenting code (otherwise this can be written in a lot of different ways). The shifts on each line is to move the data to the correct position within the 8 bit byte, nothing else.

Comment: @Lundin ah I think I now get it. But sadly still no luck. The Messages still apear wrong. Here maybe the relevant part out of the dbc file.

`data0 : 28|12@1+ (0.5,-400) [-400|1647.5] "mbar" Vector__XXX`

`data1 : 16|12@1+ (0.025,0) [0|102.375] "%" Vector__XXX`

Comment: @LundinI git it now. I needed to switch data0 with data1 because of the way information in CAN Messages are read.
Thank you so much

Comment: @98coolmen Also note the remark about me assuming big endian. It is the most common in CAN - the frames are always big endian but the payload isn't necessarily so. CANopen for example uses little endian payloads.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do some bit manipulation to pack 2 `std::uint16_t` values into 24 bit data.

```
struct input
{
    std::uint16_t a, b;
}

struct output
{
    std::uint8_t array[3];
}

output pack2into3(input vals)
{
    // Assume bit 0 is the most significant bit
    std::uint8_t first = (vals.a >> 4) & 0xFF; // Shift down 4 and mask in the lowest 8 bits of a (bit 4-12).
    std::uint8_t second_high = vals.a & 0x0F; // Mask in the lowest 4 bits of a (bit 12-16).
    std::uint8_t second low = (vals.b >> 8) & 0x0F; // Shift down 8 and mask the lowest 4 bits of b (bit 4-8).
    std::uint8_t second = (second_high << 4) | second_low; // Or together the bits from a and b which makes up the second octet.
    std::uint8_t third = vals.b & 0xFF; // Mask in the lowest 8 bits of b (bit 8-16).
    return { { first, second, third } };
}
```

Comment: `int` is never used in embedded systems, or in any system dealing with bitwise arithmetic. Unsigned types are always used and `stdint.h` types are strongly recommended.

Comment: @Lundin That is correct, but `int` is easier to type :)

Comment: Programming is all about typing a whole lot of text. People who have a problem with that ought to consider a different career. Personally I can manage to type uint32_t in a second or so... fast enough for me, what's the hurry. Or if you really don't like typing a lot of pointless text, maybe instead ditch `std::uint8_t` and go with `using std::uint8_t` at the top of the file...